# Alternate show of every 3 then every 1 item

Tags: javascript, loops, modulo, adonis.js

My current code is like this which alternates between showing every 2 then every 1 item inside loop. I want it to show every 3 then every 1 item.

I use Adonis JS template engine (Edge)

```
<div class="column">
    @each( PRO in products )

    <div>{{ PRO.id }}</div>

    @if($loop.index % 3 !== 0 && $loop.index + 1 !== products.length)
</div>
<div class="column">
    @endif
    @endeach
</div>
```

Its current result is like this:

```
<div class="column">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

and I want it to become like this:

```
<div class="column">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `n % 3 !== 0` is true 2 out of 3 times, is that the issue?

Comment: You should start a new div whenever `index % 4 == 0` or `index % 4 == 3`

Comment: @jaromanda-x current code is currect, but shows 2 1 2 1... I want 3 1 3 1.

Comment: also using `index % 4 !== 0` shows 2 1 1 2 1 1.

Comment: try `index % 4 > 1` - think of the current condition as `index % 3 > 0` ... if you had a 4:1:4:1 pattern, you'd use `index %5 > 2` --- a pattern emerges :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `3-1-3-1...` pattern, I would reason about something like:

1. Check if the current index (0-based) incremented by 1 (to make it 1-based and easier to reason about) is divisible by 4 or is one less than a multiple of 4.
2. Also, validate if the current index is not the last index of the `products` array which would prevent creating an extra empty column `<div>` at the end as per my above logic.

```html
<div class="column">
  @each(PRO in products)
    <div>{{ PRO.id }}</div>
    @if((($loop.index + 1) % 4 === 3 || ($loop.index + 1) % 4 === 0) && $loop.index + 1 !== products.length)
      </div>
      <div class="column">
    @endif
  @endeach
</div>
```

I have created a small snippet to test the above logic which you can refer to.

```js
const products = Array.from({
  length: 7
}, (_, index) => ({
  id: index + 1
}));

const columns = [];
let column = [];

products.forEach((product, index) => {
  column.push(product.id);
  const newIndex = index + 1;

  if (newIndex % 4 === 3 || newIndex % 4 === 0) {
    columns.push(column);
    column = [];
  }
});

if (column.length > 0) {
  columns.push(column);
}

console.log(columns);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: many thanks. what if I want to reverse it? I mean 1 3 1 3.. instead of 3 1 3 1.

Comment: @MehdiAzmoudeh if you read my answer you'll be able to figure it out. See in point 1 I mentioned if it is one less than a multiple of 4 i.e. `...% 4 === 3`. Change the remainder to `1` you will get the answer. Something like: `((($loop.index + 1) % 4 === 1 || ...rest of the condition`. You can manipulate it based on your requirement.